# Prevent redirect to homepage after invalid in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, postman

I'm developing a RESTful API with Laravel 5.3, so I'm testing some functions and request with my controllers. One thing I need to do is validate the request that my user sends before add a field in my database, so, I use a custom FormRequest to validate it.

When I tested my API in Postman and send my invalid request, response redirect me to homepage. After reading documentation, I found the following statement

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the
>   user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed
>   to the session so they are available for display. If the request was
>   an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be
>   returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation
>   errors.

How can I prevent this? Or there is a AJAX mode in Postman? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Also this can be achieved without overriding any function. Laravel is built to support both `Json` & normal pages.
Please change your settings in `postman` and set `Accept` to `application/json` like below
[image]

Laravel is SMART ;-)

Comment: can you please share the link if this thing is documented in laravel documentation ? Its really helpful.

Comment: how can we force that if request doesnt contain any accept header also working in apis

Comment: Wow. This works for me. Never thought about that. That's why laravel security is awesome.

Comment: This stopped me going down a rabbit hole! The more I start to use Laravel the more I start to love it

Answer (score 11):

I faced same problem in Laravel 8. In your request class, you can override failedValidation method.

```
<?php

...
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;


class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{

    ...

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422));
    }

    ...


}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your custom FormRequest extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`. Within is a function that performs the redirect called `response()`. Simply override this function within your custom FormRequest to change how invalid validations are responded to.

---

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class CustomFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Custom Failed Response
     *
     * Overrides the Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
     * response function to stop it from auto redirecting
     * and applies a API custom response format.
     *
     * @param array $errors
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function response(array $errors) {

        // Put whatever response you want here.
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status' => '422',
            'errors' => $errors,
        ], 422);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10 you have a few ways to achieve this:

### Named routes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ExampleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        
       /**
        * The route to redirect to if validation fails.
        */
        $this->redirectRoute = 'named.example.route';
    
        return [
            //User inputs => validation rules 
        ];
    }
}
```

### Named routes with parameters

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ExampleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $this->redirect = route(
            'named.example.route',
            ['example_param' => $this->param_value]
        );
        return [
            //User inputs => validation rules 
        ];
    }
}
```

### Controller Actions

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ExampleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {

       /**
        * The controller action to redirect to if validation fails.
        */
        $this->redirectAction = "ExampleController@exampleAction";

        return [
            //User inputs => validation rules 
        ];
    }
}
```

### Return Back

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ExampleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        $this->redirect = url()->previous();

        return [
            //User inputs => validation rules 
        ];
    }
}
```