# How to fix this error Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have one controller which contains three functions (register,login,forgotPassword).for login and registration it's working fine but when i try to hit an API in postman i am getting an error,previously i use seperate controller for forgotPassword() function at that time it's working fine ,now i moved that controller into USerController i am getting 500 internal server , please help me to fix this issue..
`UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Models\User;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Models\PasswordReset;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fullName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10'
            ]);
        $user = new User([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=>$request->input('mobile')           
        ]);
        $user->save();
        // User::create($request->getAttributes())->sendEmailVericationNotification();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Created user'],201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
            }
        }catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Could not create token'],500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    }

    public function forgotPassword(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Email doesn\'t found on our database'],Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        $passwordReset = PasswordReset::updateOrCreate(
            ['email' => $user->email],
            [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'token' => JWTAuth::fromUser($user)
            ]
        );
        if ($user && $passwordReset) {
            $user->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($passwordReset->token));
        }
        return response()->json(['data' => 'Reset link is send successfully, please check your inbox.'], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
    
}
```

`api.php`

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('verifyemail/{token}','VerificationController@verifyEmail');
    Route::post('/sendPasswordResetLink', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@forgotPassword');
    Route::post('/resetPassword', 'App\Http\Controllers\ChangePasswordController@resetPassword');
    //Route::get('/email/verify/{id}',[VerificationController::class,'verify']);

});
```

`in postman i am getting following error`

```
<!doctype html><html class="theme-light">
<!--
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\laravel-bookstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 427
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's on a `route('login')` in a blade somewhere. Try adding `->name('login')` to your login route.

Comment: Hello @aynber, There is no blade file in my case

Comment: If you have been reorganising routes, it might be a good idea to run `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: Could it possibly be sending an email on your ResetPasswordNotification event?

Comment: Hello @Peppermintology, if i run that command is there any chance to lost my routes (means without any effect on my working routes)

Comment: You won't lose routes. It merely clears Laravels route cache.

Comment: @Peppermintology, i run the command but still it's showing same error

Comment: What `URL` are you using to call the `login` route?

Comment: @Peppermintology, i am using this url for login http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login

Comment: The solution to this issue, regardless of where it is being triggered from, is to add `->name('login')` to your `Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login'])`. Somewhere in your code, you're referencing a named route "login", but none of your routes have `->name('login')` so it's failing.

Comment: @TimLewis,after adding name('login') i am getting this error Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\laravel-bookstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117

Comment: Sweet, so we fixed that error. For the new one, I _believe_ that happens when `$this->validate()` fails; it tries to redirect to the `GET` version of the current URL (which is `/api/auth/login` (although I could be wrong; not sure API requests). Does your code work if you pass valid parameters?

Comment: @TimLewis, yes it's working for login and register api

Comment: Cool, then consider using this approach to validation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators. I personally have no experience using `$this->validate()`, as I prefer the manual validation method regardless, but you might be able to adjust it to work with API request (i.e. returning a `JSON` response instead of redirecting). Alternatively, this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235059/3965631

Comment: @TimLewis, i am not using any redirects. i am returning only json response

Comment: I know you're not, but the code is. Like I said, `$this->validate()` will perform a redirect when validation fails.

Comment: ok i follow the doccumentation once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mostly, I think, this error often occurs when a route protected by a middleware is being accessed by an unauthorized/unauthenticated resource. I think you should check if the jwt token is valid by removing the `auth:api` middleware and replace it with this:

`return response()->json([ 'valid' => auth()->check() ]);`

Comment: How we can handle such situation in the API route files?

Answer (score 34):

Add new config at headers

```
"Accept"=>"application/json"
```

Laravel will check the configuration for "**Accept**", it will return the web page or html if no value is set at "Accept" by default

[Source help](https://programmierfrage.com/items/laravel-sanctum-route-login-not-defined)

[image: PostMan Headers Screenshot for example]

Answer (score 20):

the route is protected. include Accept application/json in request and it will show:
{
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}

Comment: I believe this should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the .htaccess file was missing the command to accept the Authorization command.

Command:

**CGIPassAuth on**

Answer (score 1):

Updated **.htaccess** with the following command
`CGIPassAuth on` works perfectly fine for me.

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ server.php
  
  CGIPassAuth on
</IfModule>
```

> Thanks @Otavio Silva.